# How to print plain text in Unity + Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, unity-game-engine

How to print plain text in Unity + Visual Studio?

Printing to console with

```
Debug.Log()
```

prints with decorations. I need just plain text.

Answer (score 2):

Debug.Log is not just displaying the log in the Console tab. It is also saving to a [file](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html).

*If using the Editor, you can find this log file at:*

**Windows:**

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Unity\Editor\
```

**MacOs:**

```
~/Library/Logs/Unity/Editor.log
```

---

*When you build it, you can find the log file at:*

**Windows:**

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\LocalLow\<CompanyName>\<ProductName>\output_log.txt
```

**MacOs:**

```
~/Library/Logs/Unity/Player.log
```

**Linux:**

```
~/.config/unity3d/<CompanyName>/<ProductName>/Player.log
```

**Universal Windows Platform:**

Desktop - `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages<productname>\TempState\UnityPlayer.log`

Windows Phone - Can be retrieved with [Windows Phone Power Tools](https://wptools.codeplex.com/).

---

If that's not enough for you then you have to implement your own. Make a simple log function that saves to the end of file with any `System.IO` API such as `File.AppendText`.

Comment: In log file it allso accompanied with a lot of not needed (for my purposes) data, like location of log call, which I don't need

Comment: Ok. That's why I told you to use `File.AppendText` or any standard `System.IO` API  to make your own if the built-in one is not enough for you.

Comment: I did not know that Debug.Log logged to a file too. Handy.

Comment: @Draco18s I didn't know either and found this out in a really bad way because it concatenates/appends the logs. I left the Editor in play mode running overnight with so many `Debug.Log` every frame. The next time, I woke up, my computer has a notification that says it was running out of storage space.  I scanned my computer for file usage and found the path and it was the one in my answer. I looked at the log file there it was more than 20GB. That's how I came to this.